# Unix piping and redirection

Tags: unix, redirect, tr, piping

> Assume you want to read as input the file ‘passwords.txt’, change
> every uppercase letter to a lowercase letter and every ‘$ ’ to a ‘# ’,
> then save the result back to that same file (overwriting it). How
> would you do this with the tr command? HINT: Use piping and file
> redirection.

I tried these 2 commands, but they didn't work. I think the file got truncated by the system, so that the passwords.txt becomes empty after.

> cat passwords.txt | tr '[A-Z'!']' '[a-z'#']'
>
> tr ‘[A-Z"!"]’ ‘[a-z"#"]’ < passwords.txt > passwords.txt

I know we can do something like writing it to a temp file and use "&&" to change the temp file name to passwords.txt . However, this is a homework problem and we haven't learn about "&&" yet, so I believe that there must be another way to do this with just piping and redirecting only.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the file got truncated by the system, so that the
>   passwords.txt becomes empty after.

You are correct.  You'd need to redirect the `tr` output to a temporary file and move the temporary file to the original one.

Moreover, the use of quotes around `!` (I assume that it was intended to be `$`) and `#` is superfluous.  You could say:

```
cat /etc/passwd | tr 'A-Z$' 'a-z#' > temp && mv temp /etc/passwd
```

or eliminate the useless use of `cat` by using indirection:

```
tr 'A-Z$' 'a-z#' < /etc/passwd > temp && mv temp /etc/passwd
```

Here `&&` is a control operator separating two commands.  If you say:

```
command1 && command2
```

then command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero, i.e. if command1 is successful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way without using `&&`,

```
echo "$(tr '[A-Z$]' '[a-z#]' < sample)" > sample
```

**Test**:

```
sat:~# cat > sample
sample TEXT
$test
sat:~# 
sat:~# echo "$(tr '[A-Z$]' '[a-z#]' < sample)" > sample
sat:~# cat sample
sample text
#test
sat:~#
```